# OpenMP loop gives different result to the same serial loop

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, multicore, reduction

I have some serial code:

```
double* a = malloc((1000000) * sizeof(double));
double* b = malloc((1000000) * sizeof(double));
double totalA = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

    if (i == 0) {
        a[i] = sin(i);
    }

    b[i] = sin(i+1);

    if (i < 1000000-1) {
        a[i+1] = b[i];
    }

    totalA += a[i];
}
```

The output of `totalA` after this serial loop is `0.232883978073`.

I then have an OpenMP version of this (note: all variables are re-initialised):

```
double* a = malloc((1000000) * sizeof(double));
double* b = malloc((1000000) * sizeof(double));
double totalA = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:totalA)
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

    if (i == 0) {
        a[i] = sin(i);
    }

    b[i] = sin(i+1);

    if (i < 1000000-1) {
        a[i+1] = b[i];
    }

    totalA += a[i];
}
```

However, the output of `totalA` from this code is `-0.733714826779`.

I can't figure out for the life of me why it is different.

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

After some more playing around it seems that the `if` statements within the loop are ignored oddly. The actual statements within the `if` blocks are executed on all iterations of the loop (as if the `if` clause doesn't exist).

For example, changing the `if` block to:

```
if (i < 555555) {
    a[i+1] = b[i];
}
```

seems to make absolutely no difference.

I am still none the wiser as to what is going on here.

Comment: The other answer has scored much better than mine. Please give it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code contains a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). The conflicting statements are the assignment `a[i+1] = b[i];` that writes to the array `a` and the statement `totalA += a[i];` that reads from `a`.

In your code there is no guarantee that the iteration that is responsible for writing to a particular location in the array is executed before the iteration that reads from that location.

To further demonstrate the issue, ordering the loop segment that contains the conflicting statements resolves the problem (but is most likely devastating for your performance):

```
#pragma omp parallel for ordered reduction(+:totalA)    
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

   if (i == 0) {
     a[i] = sin(i);
   }

  b[i] = sin(i+1);

  #pragma omp ordered
  {
    if (i < 1000000-1) {
      a[i+1] = b[i];
    }

    totalA += a[i];
  }
}
```

It is probably better to avoid the problem altogether and rewrite your program to get rid of the loop-carried dependency:

```
#define N 1000000

double* a = malloc(N * sizeof(double));
double* b = malloc(N * sizeof(double));
double totalA = 0;

a[0] = sin(0);
totalA += a[0];

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:totalA)
for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
  b[i] = sin(i + 1);
  a[i + 1] = b[i];
  totalA += a[i + 1];
}

b[N - 1] = sin(N);
```

Finally, note that, as `sin(0) ≈ 0.0`, the statements

```
a[0] = sin(0);
totalA += a[0];
```

can simply be replaced by

```
a[0] = 0.0;
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenMP and I assumed it would take care of that by itself.

Comment: @2501 by putting #pragma omp for on the loop you are asserting that it can be executed in parallel. It is *your* job to check the safety of that assertion, not the compiler's. (In general the compiler can't do it since there may be calls to separately compiled code in the loop which may not even have been written when the compiler is run!)

Comment: People seem to think your answer is much better than mine (+5 is a great answer for OpenMP). Did I make a mistake in my answer? Is my answer misleading?

Comment: @Zboson I think your answer is fine. You immediately jumped to a solution for the problem, where I focused more on explaining the problem. Perhaps people valued that explanation? I would say are answers are nicely complementary.

Comment: Stefans answer explained to me why I was having the issue (which is why I up voted it). However, @Zboson answer 'solved' my problem which is why I marked it as the 'solution'. As you mentioned Stefan, both answers complement one another and both assisted me. Thank you both.

Comment: Stefan, you could append @Zboson's simple fix to the end of your answer and I will accept it as the best solution. Hopefully then anyone else who has this issue will have both an explanation and solution?

Comment: I'm glad your replaced `totalA += b[i];` with `totalA += a[i + 1];`. I meant to suggest that afterwards. Also, I think you meant to write `sin(0) = 0.0` instead of `≈ 0.0`. Or maybe you mean `sin(x) ≈ x` for `x << 1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your main loop to:

```
a[0] = sin(0);
for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
    b[i] = sin(i+1);
    a[i+1] = b[i];
    totalA += a[i];
}
totalA += a[N-1];
b[N-1] = sin(N);
```

Let's call the iterator for thread1 `i1` and thread2 `i2`. Then when e.g. `i2=i1+1` the write to `a[i1+1]` and the read at `a[i2]` will be the same address and the value read or written will depend on the order of which thread is first. This is a race condition.

A simple fix is to observe that `totalA = a[0] + b[0] + b[1] + ... b[N-2]`.

```
a[0] = sin(0);
totalA += a[0];
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:totalA)
for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
    b[i] = sin(i+1);
    a[i+1] = b[i];
    totalA += b[i];
}
b[N-1] = sin(N);
```

This produces `0.232883978073` for `N=1000000`.